# Rubymotion query using Nano-Store In Motion

Tags: ruby, rubymotion

I have a method in a iOS application that is querying a database and then putting the data in a ruby loop. I have the loop working to dynamically add a number to the ruby loop but it is pulling up all the users.

```
# Query all children in database

child = Child.all

# Loop through children and add count.

count = child.count
0.upto(count - 1) do |c|
  p "#{@child.each do |child| child.first_name end}" + "['#{c}']"
end
```

With this set of query and loop it is giving me the following answers:

"[Child:0x8dee0, Child:0x8de2860]['0']",
"[Child:0x8dee0, Child:0x8de2860]['1']"

Instead of giving me the same child for each number I need it to query answers as follows:

"[Child:0x8dee0]['0']",
"[Child:0x8de2860]['1']"

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your loop is trying to print the first names of the children in your array,
try this:

```
0.upto(count - 1) do |c|
  p child[c].first_name
end
```

Alternatively, you could skip the count altogether:

```
child.each do |achild|
  p achild.first_name
end
```